# Creating dialog element inside tableViewController

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross, mvxbind

i have a tableview , under that tableview i need to create a dialog element(RadioElement) ,which would have some cells to check and take user input .
as this class is subclass of MvxTableViewController not MvxDialogViewController ,
I am not able to access rootElement,section and other things to achieve my goal .

So how can i create rootElement in a subclass of MvxTableViewController .

Any suggestion would be appriciated .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't sound like it's a straight-forward thing to do.

`Monotouch.Dialog` is an impressively complex beast and it relies on a few properties and methods in the owning `DialogViewController`.

It's probably easier to tackle your current problem by recoding your table as a Dialog and then adding custom cells to represent your non-Dialog cells.

Comment: Thanks stuart , i thought the same , this tableView is at top of hierarchy (extensively used), here upon clicking on different cell(custom cells) i load different viewModel ,i cant make this as dialog , 
i have to leave the thought of putting RadioElement in this class rather i ll go for custom cells that will load in  new  section .